# Detect if current time is between two set up times

Tags: java, android, date

I've a program which includes service. This program has settings which allows user to set up, disable and enable time. Between these two times (if option is enabled of course), the program should not work.

I'm actually having hard time to do this. I've already sucessfully converted "disabled" and "enabled" time in milliseconds. I have following code but it doesn't work as expected. I want to detect if current time is between two set up times, so i can disable service at that time.

```
public boolean isCurrentTimeBetween_enableDisable() {       
    long sysTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if((sysTime > disableTime && sysTime < enableTime)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Anyone can give me better hint?

**UPDATE:**

If user selects lets say

- Disable hour: 15:00
- Enable hour: 22:00

Then code work as expected.

But if user selects lets say:

- Disable hour: 22:00
- Enable hour: 06:00

Then its obviously that Enable hour is the NEXT day. So i wrote the following code:

```
if(todaysDisableDate(context).getTime() > enableAt.getTime()) {
    enableCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    enableAt = formatEnableDate.parse(enableCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" +(enableCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + enableCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + endHours_string + ":" + endMinutes_string);
}
```

Code below is getting the actual date.

```
public Date todaysDisableDate(Context context) {
    Calendar disableCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    getTimeValues_preferences((ContextWrapper) context, true, false); // this only gets a string for hour and minute (which is set up in preferences )

    Date disableAt = null;

    try {
        disableAt = formatDisableDate.parse(disableCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"-"+(disableCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+disableCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+" "+startHours_string+":"+startMinutes_string); // današnji datum z današnjo uro
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return disableAt;
}

public Date todaysEnableDate(Context context) { 
    Calendar enableCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    getTimeValues_preferences((ContextWrapper) context, false, true);

    Date enableAt = null;
    try {
        enableAt = formatEnableDate.parse(enableCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"-"+(enableCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+enableCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+" "+endHours_string+":"+endMinutes_string); // današnji datum z današnjo uro

        if(todaysDisableDate(context).getTime() > enableAt.getTime()) {         
            enableCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            enableAt = formatEnableDate.parse(enableCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"-"+(enableCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+enableCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+" "+endHours_string+":"+endMinutes_string);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }
    return enableAt;
}
```

Code is working fine if service starts before 00:00. But if the service starts after midnight (of next day), then i'm getting false from method `isCurrentTimeBetween_enableDisable()`, because methods `todaysDisableDate(Context context)` and `todaysEnableDate(Context context)` are pulling out the next day (the same day as system hour is in)

Comment: Well that looks somewhat clumsy (I'd prefer just `return sysTime > disableTime && sysTime < enableTime;`) but should work. You've said that it "doesn't work as expected" but there's absolutely no indication of *how* it's not working.

Comment: possible use of `joda-time` library?

Answer (score 2):

Do you *have to* compare dates in your code? If that's a project requirement then you can ignore the following.

Otherwise, I think you can use `AlarmManager` to create the feature without actually comparing the date. You can create a "Enable" intent and a "Disable" intent for the `AlarmManager` to fire at the scheduled time. Something like this:

Register your alarms when the user confirmed the time schedule.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, yourAlarmReceiver.class);  //or implicit with action
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating (typeConstant, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, pIntent);
```

You just need to figure out what `triggerAtMillis` is to determine the first shot of that broadcast, and `intervalMillis` will be a full day, which is a constant in the `AlarmManager` class.

Setup your custom receiver class (which I wrote as `yourAlarmReceiver`) which should extend `BroadcastReceiver`, and register the receiver in your service. In the `onReceive()` you should perform the corresponding actions based on `intent.getAction()`. Don't forget to register your receiver with an intent filter if you want more customization.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
switch(intent.getAction()){
case "enable": //enable if not enabled
case "disable": //disable if not disabled
default: break;
}
}
```

In this way it may save you some time from struggling with comparing today and tomorrow. You can determine the time of the very first shot by getting the current system time, probably in 24-hour format, and determine if your intended time has already passed. Whether it's been passed, you just need to set the initial firing time to `currentTime + difference`.

Hope it will shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the start date and end date itself...and not convert them to miliseconds. But this is only if you're not sure.

```
private String compareStringOne = "9:45";
private String compareStringTwo = "1:45";

SimpleDateFormat inputParser = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.US);

private void compareDates(){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    date = parseDate(hour + ":" + minute);
    dateCompareOne = parseDate(compareStringOne);
    dateCompareTwo = parseDate(compareStringTwo);

    if ( dateCompareOne.before( date ) && dateCompareTwo.after(date)) {
        //This is where you determine if the date is inbetween
    }
}

private Date parseDate(String date) {

    try {
        return inputParser.parse(date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        return new Date(0);
    }
}
```